# What if there is no reaction to close requests?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I came across [Exception in thread “Thread-0” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890714/exception-in-thread-thread-0-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-joda-time-rea) yesterday evening.

The title seems good, but the rest of the question is written in Portuguese. I downvoted and closed as unclear ... and typically, others would do the same, and within a few hours, sometimes minutes, the question would be deleted.

But well, what if a tree falls in the forest ... and nobody is there to notice? That is what happened here - the question is still around hours later. Interestingly enough, other poor questions asked around that time received appropriate feedback much quicker.

I guess it would be a misuse of flagging to contact a moderator for something that *should* be handled by the community. I also guess that writing up a specific meta question (like this one) isn't a viable, sustainable option.

So, how do we move fallen trees if nobody is there to move them?

Comment: Patience? It's only been 10 hours... It's the weekend, a time that's pretty slow, and (from what I understand) the close vote queue is... huge. Your vote to close sticks around for 14 days... give it some time.

Comment: The close queue is like always huge. And the patience thing is two fold: as I have noticed that chances of poor questions being dealt with appropriately rather declines over time. If it doesn't vanish quickly, some seem to stick forever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some non-english posts do get detected by the [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) and then reported in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and [SOBOTICS](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) but this one must have slipped through the cracks and no human brought it under the eyes of the inhabitants of one those mentioned rooms. SOCVR specially handles [cv-pls] requests as stated in their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq).

If you hate the moderation-by-mob mentality try a tag specific room to get some attention on it.

Otherwise you should practice patience and hope that within 4 days your close vote gets seen by reviewers in the close vote queue. That is that queue with 6 to 8 thousand review items in it, so that is a bit of a gamble.

Comment: Smokedetector catches only non-latin posts and hence doesn't detect Portuguese. There has been some discussions regarding adding Non English post detection to Fire Alarm, but it is still in the design phase.